# which determines the order of convergence, mean or variance?

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

If I have a sequence of random variable $X_n$, and $EX_n=o(\frac{1}{n}),var(X_n)=o(\frac{1}{n^4})$, is the stochastic order  $X_n= o_p(\frac{1}{n})$ or $o_p(\frac{1}{n^2})$? I perfer the latter. Does it mean if I want to check the order of a random variable, I just need calculate the convergence speed of variance, and ensure the convergence of mean is engough, no matter what the convergence speed of mean?

Comment: @nicomezi EX=0 only when $ n \rightarrow \infty$ I think.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, and I have corrected it now.